# Getting back information added with multiple calls to a function

Tags: php

I want to have a function and then use it multiple times with different parameters.

For example:

```
<?php
    class Test {
       var $test; 

      public function func($val) {
         $this->test = $val;
      }

      public function buildFunc() {
          if(!empty($this->test)) {
              $ret = $this->test;
          }
          return $ret;
      }
   }   

?>
```

Then on calling page:

```
$test = new Test;
$test->func("test1");
$test->func("test2");

echo $test->buildFunc();
```

Then it prints test2 on the screen. And I want it to print out both of them.

Comment: not clear what you want. how would your function call look like?

Comment: Do you want the $test->buildFunc(); to print both `test1 and test2`?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with OOP. Try to do the same using two functions that communicate through a global variable if that would be less confusing.

Comment: I’m struggling to understand what you’re trying to achieve. Maybe look at `ArrayAccess` if you want a function to return a different value every time you call it?

Comment: Do not use `var $test;`, this is from PHP4 and it's equivalent to make the property `public`. If you are fine with the property being `public`, then declare it as `public` instead of `var`. Learn about [visibility](http://www.php.net/oop5.visibility) and declare the visibility in all your properties and functions.

Answer (score 3):

Either create 2 instances of your object;

```
$test1 = new Test;
$test1->func("test1");
$test2 = new Test;
$test2->func("test2");

echo $test1->buildFunc();
echo $test2->buildFunc();
```

Or make test an array;

```
class Test {
   var $test = array(); 

  public function func($val) {
     $this->test[] = $val;
  }

  public function buildFunc() {
      return print_r($this->test, true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you mean that you want to store all values? Then use an array:

```
  public function func($val) {
     $this->test[] = $val;
  }

  public function buildFunc() {
      return $this->test
  }
```

And then work with the result as with an array.

Answer (score 0):

Push the variables to an array

```
<?php
    class Test {
       var $test; 

      public function __construct(){
        $this->test=array();//Declare $test as an array
      }
      public function func($val) {
       $this->test[]=$val;//Push to array
      }

      public function buildFunc() {
          if(!empty($this->test)) {
              $ret = implode(",",$this->test);
          }
          return $ret;
      }
   }   

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. your code does exactly what are you telling it to do. Consider situation when you have no OOP:

```
$str = 'test 1';
$str = 'test 2';

echo $str; //prints test 2
```

So you need to echo them separately as if it wont be an OOP situation.

```
$test = new Test;

$test->func("test1");
echo $test->buildFunc();

$test->func("test2");
echo $test->buildFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling the method create 2 instances of the test object.

```
$test = new Test;
$test->func("test1");
echo $test->buildFunc();

$test2 = new Test;
$test2->func("test2");
echo $test2->buildFunc();
```

if you dont want to create 2 instances you have to make a array instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you say both do you mean something like

test1test2

or do you want

test1
   test2

For the first option you can just append the string:

```
<?php
    class Test {
        var $test; 

        public function func($val) {
            $this->test = $test . $val; <-- add val to the end
        }

        public function buildFunc() {
            if(!empty($this->test)) {
                $ret = $this->test;
            }
            return $ret;
        }
    }   
?>
```

For the second:

```
<?php
    class Test {
        var $test = array(); 

        public function func($val) {
            $this->test[] = $val; <-- add val to 
        }

        public function buildFunc() {
            if(!empty($this->test)) {
                foreach($test as $item){
                echo $item . "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: the `foreach` should be inside the `buildFunc()` in place of the `return $ret;` for your class to work

Answer (score 0):

How about create a constructor and initialize the value of test and concat the second value.

```
<?php
    class Test {
       var $test; 

        public function __construct($init){
            $this->test = $init;
        }

      public function func($val) {
         $this->test .= $val;
         return $this;
      }

      public function buildFunc() {

          if(!empty($this->test)) {
              $ret = $this->test;
          }
          return $ret;
      }
   }   

$test = new Test("test1");
$test->func("test2");


echo $test->buildFunc();

?>
```